# Installing Openresty on Ubuntu server

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I tried this document http://openresty.org/en/getting-started.html but I faced a problem with "content_by_lua_block"

Then I tried this document https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-openresty-web-framework-for-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04 and I faced problem in runing Openresty with "systemd"

I just have a clean Digitalocean droplet and want to install Openresty on it and work with lua. Is there any standard and working article for installing Openresty and config it?

Answer (score 0):

I built [resty-install.sh](https://gist.github.com/DarkWiiPlayer/126c4247814b70434069d7cdf4b300ce) a while ago for personal use. Maybe you can use that (as-is, or after modifying it a little).

Be warned though: it does install a custom launch script for openresty that makes it look for `openresty.conf` in the current directory, instead of `nginx.conf` in the install directory. (line 50 of the script)

Also, it writes an example configuration to `/usr/local/openresty/example.conf`, which you might not need. (everything after line 55)

Comment: How could I use it? I just copied it in /home/install.sh and did not work

Comment: this is the error "No gmake nor make found in PATH."

Comment: That's weird... The script installs `build-essentials`, which should include `make` on ubuntu...

Comment: Are you not running the script as root? If not, then it won't work, as it won't be able to install the required packages using `apt`. Either way, I suggest not running the script directly, but going through it line by line and picking out what you need.

Comment: I`m facing this now  "unknown directive "content_by_lua_block"

Comment: Then you're running vanilla nginx, not openresty

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I followed this article again https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-openresty-web-framework-for-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04

The problem was we should kill the Openresty is already running on port 80 exactly before step 3